# Magento 2.3.5 Customer registration email domain @xxx.com.xx crash

Tags: email, domain

I am new with Magento and I am using Magento 2.3.5.

When I test on the Create new customer account, fill up the field Sign-in information with using email domain with @xxx.com.tw , @xxx.com.jp or @xxx.com.hk , the server gets crashed.

Please advise how to fix it. Million thanks.